# Difference between measuring rates as $E(X/Y)$ vs. $E(X)/E(Y)$?

Tags: expected-value, difference-in-difference

I'm working on a difference-in-differences (DiD) analysis for a healthcare study measuring # hospitalizations (X) per # eligible months (Y).

Simplifying the math a bit - my actuary colleagues like to measure the DiD in the aggregate as sum(X)/sum(Y) = E(X)/E(Y) vs. the member-level rate I prefer (the average treatment effect), average of (X/Y) = E(X/Y).

I know via Jensen's Inequality that E(X)/E(Y) <= E(X/Y) given 1/Y is convex and X and Y are independent (actually, a fair assumption in this case).

Question: Which method is preferred for estimating the DiD treatment effect? Is one more "correct" than the other, or are they simply addressing different questions?

Answer (score 5):

Recall that the [expectation is linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties), so

$$
E[a + b X] = a + c E[X]
$$

Let's say that $E[X] = 0$, in such a case if we have $Y = cX$, where $c$ is some constant, $E[Y] = E[cX] = c E[X] = c \times 0$, so $E[X]\,/\,E[Y]$ would be undefined regardless of what $c$ is. But we can shift $X$ and $Y$ by a constant $a$, so that $E[X + a] = 0 + a$, and $E[Y + a] = 0 + a$, then $E[X+a]\,/\,E[Y+a] = a \,/\, a = 1$, regardless of what $c$ is. This example shows that comparing expectations to learn $c$ easily breaks apart.

Another problem with comparing expectations is [ecological fallacy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125683/pearson-correlation-has-quizzy-results/125686#125686) and the related [Simpson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox) that show how the relations in aggregated vs raw data (or differently aggregated) may be completely different.

I am *not* saying that comparing expected values does not make sense. I am trying to say that it doesn't necessarily tell you how $X$ and $Y$ are related to each other, just how their averages are related.

Comment: Thanks - so in your opinion you can't compare E(X)/E(Y) to E(X/Y), it's not as simple as E(X)/E(Y) = c * E(X/Y)? I'm also curious if E[E(X)/E(Y)] and Var(E(X)/E(Y)) can be defined.

Comment: @RobertF I don't understand your comment. As for E[E(X)/E(Y)], E(X) and E(Y) are just numbers, so there is no expected value or variance for their ratio.

Comment: Link to another similar post that may answer my question I think: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172196/relation-between-expectation-of-ratio-and-ratio-of-expectation