# Is the ratio of medians a good approximation of the median of ratios?

Tags: probability, distributions, mean, median

For two random variables $X$ and $Y$, does it hold that the median of $\frac{X}{Y}$ is approximately equal to the median of $X$ divided by the median of $Y$:

$$
F_{X/Y}^{-1}(0.5) \approx \frac{F_{X}^{-1}(0.5)}{F_{Y}^{-1}(0.5)}? 
$$

Could you please provide a derivation?

For means this does not [hold](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172196/relation-between-expectation-of-ratio-and-ratio-of-expectation) in general. I did a short experiment where I took random samples from two distributions and computed the mean/median of the ratios and the ratio of means/medians. I repeated this several times. The ratios of means were sometimes way off, but the ratios of medians were always close to the median of ratios. So I'm wondering if there is a theoretical justification for that or if my experiments are just not extensive enough (I tested with 16 different distribution pairs).

I'm attaching experiment code if it helps:

```r
library(tidyverse)

two_normals <- function (mu1, mu2, sigma1 = 1, sigma2 = 2) {
  return (function (nsamp) {
    x <- rnorm(nsamp, mu1, sigma1)
    y <- rnorm(nsamp, mu2, sigma2)
    
    return (list(x = x, y = y))
  })
}

two_truncated_normals <- function (mu1, mu2, sigma1 = 1, sigma2 = 2) {
  return (function (nsamp) {
    x <- truncnorm::rtruncnorm(nsamp, 0, Inf, mu1, sigma1)
    y <- truncnorm::rtruncnorm(nsamp, 0, Inf, mu2, sigma2)
    
    return (list(x = x, y = y))
  })
}

two_truncated_normals_correlated <- function (mu1, mu2, sigma1, 
                                      sigma2 = 2, linear_term = 1) {
  return (function (nsamp) {
    x <- truncnorm::rtruncnorm(nsamp, 0, Inf, mu1, sigma1)
    y <- x + linear_term * rnorm(nsamp, 0, sigma2)
    
    return (list(x = x, y = y))
  })
}

two_truncated_normals_correlated_negative <- function (mu1, mu2, 
            sigma1, sigma2 = 2, linear_term = 1) {
  return (function (nsamp) {
    x <- truncnorm::rtruncnorm(nsamp, 0, Inf, mu1, sigma1)
    y <- -x + linear_term * rnorm(nsamp, 0, sigma2)
    y <- y - min(y) + 1
    
    return (list(x = x, y = y))
  })
}

first_normal_second_gamma <- function (mu1, sigma1 = 1, shape, scale) {
  return (function (nsamp) {
    x <- rnorm(nsamp, mu1, sigma1)
    y <- rgamma(nsamp, shape, scale = scale)
    
    return (list(x = x, y = y))
  })
}

first_gamma_second_normal <- function (shape, scale, mu1, sigma1 = 1) {
  return (function (nsamp) {
    y <- rnorm(nsamp, mu1, sigma1)
    x <- rgamma(nsamp, shape, scale = scale)
    
    return (list(x = x, y = y))
  })
}

experiments <- c(
  "two_normals" = two_normals(20, 20),
  "two_truncated_normals_1" = two_truncated_normals(20, 20),
  "two_truncated_normals_2" = two_truncated_normals(20, 20, 10000),
  "two_truncated_normals_3" = two_truncated_normals(20, 20, 1, 10000),
  "two_truncated_normals_4" = two_truncated_normals(20, 20, 1000, 1),
  "two_truncated_normals_5" = two_truncated_normals(20, 20, 1000, 
                                                    1000),
  "two_truncated_normals_6" = two_truncated_normals(2, 2, 1, 1),
  "two_truncated_normals_7" = two_truncated_normals(2, 10, 1, 1),
  "two_truncated_normals_correlated_1" = 
    two_truncated_normals_correlated(20, 20, 1, 1, 1),
  "two_truncated_normals_correlated_2" = 
    two_truncated_normals_correlated(20, 20, 1, 4, 1),
  "two_truncated_normals_correlated_3" = 
   two_truncated_normals_correlated_negative(20, 20, 1, 1, 1),
  "two_truncated_normals_correlated_4" = 
   two_truncated_normals_correlated_negative(20, 20, 1, 4, 1),
  "first_normal_second_gamma_1" = first_normal_second_gamma(20, 1, 1, 
                                                            20),
  "first_normal_second_gamma_2" = first_normal_second_gamma(20, 1, 20, 
                                                            200),
  "first_gamma_second_normal_1" = first_gamma_second_normal(1, 20, 20, 
                                                            1),
  "first_gamma_second_normal_2" = first_gamma_second_normal(20, 200, 
                                                            20, 1)
)

n       <- 100
nsamp   <- 1000
out_df  <- tibble()

set.seed(1)

for (i in 1:length(experiments)) {
  mean_of_ratios   <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = n)
  ratio_of_means   <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = n)
  median_of_ratios <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = n)
  ratio_of_medians <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = n)
  
  for (j in 1:n) {
    samples <- experiments[[i]](nsamp)
    x       <- samples[[1]]
    y       <- samples[[2]]

    mean_of_ratios[j]   <- mean(x / y)
    ratio_of_means[j]   <- mean(x) / mean(y)
    median_of_ratios[j] <- median(x / y)
    ratio_of_medians[j] <- median(x) / median(y)
  }
  
  df <- tibble(
    "experiment"       = names(experiments)[i],
    "mean_of_ratios"   = mean_of_ratios,
    "ratio_of_means"   = ratio_of_means,
    "median_of_ratios" = median_of_ratios,
    "ratio_of_medians" = ratio_of_medians,
  )
  
  out_df <- out_df %>% bind_rows(df)
}

ggplot(out_df, aes(x = mean_of_ratios, y = ratio_of_means)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ experiment, scales = "free") +
  geom_abline(aes(slope = 1, intercept = 0))

ggplot(out_df, aes(x = median_of_ratios, y = ratio_of_medians)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ experiment, scales = "free") +
  geom_abline(aes(slope = 1, intercept = 0))
```

Images:
[image: Ratio of means]
[image: Ratio of medians]

Comment: I uploaded the images, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample: Consider $X$ distributed $0.4\delta_{0.1}+0.6\delta_{100}$, where $\delta_z$ denotes the Dirac measure in $z$, i.e., $X$ is 0.1 with probability 0.4 and 100 with probability 0.6. Distribution of $Y$ is $0.6\delta_{0.1}+0.4\delta_{100}$. Med(X)=100, Med(Y)=0.1, Med(X)/Med(Y)=1000. The distribution of $X/Y$ is $0.16*\delta_{0.001}+0.48\delta_1+0.36\delta_{1000}$, its median is 1.

Comment: I guess it would work similarly with a bimodal continuous distribution, something like $X \sim 0.4\text{Normal}(20, 1) + 0.6\text{Normal}(60, 1)$ and $Y$ the same but the proportions reversed. Just to have a continuous distribution, which is my use-case. I evaluated it empirically and it looks like it is also a counter example. Thank you!

Comment: @gregorp Yeah, such things can be done with continuous distributions as well. To approximate my example you can just choose low variance normals around 0.1 and 100.